# Configuration question

Tags: configuration

I use Tor to watch al jazeera. 
I used the be able to watch their videos but lately what ever I do, I cannot watch them. 
How to configure Tor and Flash Player to watch videos on al jazeera?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use :

```
ExitNodes {qa}
StrictNodes 1
```

in your `torrc`.

And also it would be very useful if you will add your torrc config to your question and tell us a little bit more about your setup - it will help us to help you

Comment: My setup is straight forward, I have a desktop connected thru Comcast I use Firefox and Tor, Tor only to watch add your Al Jaazera. I also use Comodo Security suite and that's it. Nothing special or fancy. Where can I find my tor config?

Comment: @Frenchy take a look at  Tor folder, a file named `torrc` - is there one? How do you run your Tor binary? with a browser or separately?

Comment: Might be worth adding a comment re: flash and proxy obedience. Do they not offer html5 video that will work through Tor Browser?